# Google Script: Adding 1 to a value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add 1 to the value of a cell in a Google Spreadsheet when a certain event happens. But instead of...say changing -6 to -5, it changes it to -61. What's wrong with my code?

```
var Spending = sheet.getRange("B2");
var SPEND = [Spending.getCell(1, 1).getValue()];

**EVENT TRIGGERED**

SPEND = SPEND+1;
    Spending.setValue(SPEND);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that was reading the value as a string and simply concatenate it. Try to parse the the var SPEND to Integer.

example:

`SPEND = parseInt(SPEND)+1` or `SPEND = Number(SPEND)+1`

Answer (score 0):

for some reason i have yet to fully discover (mainly through lack on needing to know the deeper answer), + is treated as a concatenation for anything but an integer value. so unless the var is declared as an intiger, it's treated as a string. if it's a string, the "+" means to concat, not perform a mathematical operation. "-" doesn't seem to have the same dual usage, only being used for mathematical operations.

Hope that helps!